# Apple Display/UI Scaling

Tags: display, screen, font, resolution

I am a new owner of a M1 MacBook Pro and a long time Windows user and I have a problem with how the text is displayed on my screen.

The Mac's screen itself looks fine, but when I connected it to my usual 43" 4K display (LG 43UN700-B) I noticed the horrendous lack of proper scaling.

I tried to do some research and found this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421858/how-does-display-scaling-work-on-mac?newreg=cc1bbe15d4144b4c8bf5fd4f0df8273c), from which gathered there is no UI scaling in macOS (Ventura) and I either have to accept everything beeing too big with 1080p resolution to use integer scaling or use native resolution, which looks blurry on my display on macOS (I suspect this could be due to lack of sub-pixel antialiasing, but I tried turning it on via terminal to no avail).

To summarize:

- Is there any way to change the size of UI elements **without** changing the screen resolution (e.g. setting display scaling to 125% on Windows)? I don't mind using terminal, another window manager (if that's a thing on macOS) or some weird hacks.

Also buying a screen with higher DPI is not an option since it would mean buying a 8K screen   which is not really a thing now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.  Questions should be one topic  per post. This could be split into two separate questions: UI elements and font anti-ailasing.  Also, please ensure that the question hasn’t been asked/answered previously by searching for the topic(s) of interest.

Comment: There is no "M1 Mac Pro." Perhaps you meant "M1 MacBook Pro?" it would be good to edit your question and change that to the correct Mac model...

Comment: I did edit the question, but the model has honestly no bearing on this problem, since it is a software and not a hardware problem...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to change the size of UI elements without changing
> the screen resolution?

The Scaling options on macOS exist for the express function of changing the size of UI elements. The default Retina scaling on a laptop's screen makes everything 2x as big as it would otherwise be, using the full pixel resolution of the display.

The resolution doesn't change: just the 'zoom level'. Don't be fooled by *'Looks like 1080p'*.

Your display has a pixel density of 102ppi, which is very low, and so you're always going to see some lack of smoothness.  For one reason or another, macOS has removed the code for sub-pixel rendering, so displays of this sort don't look great.

I would have thought that native resolution would give the best results. Use any kind of scaling is, as you say, going to make things enormous. If you really find the native display both too small and too blurry, you could try a 'non-integer' scaling value, maybe 2560 x 1440.

> buying a screen with higher DPI is not an option since it would mean
> buying a 8K screen

A 27" 4K display would show a significant improvement, at 163ppi.

Comment: "The resolution doesn't change: just the 'zoom level'. Don't be fooled by 'Looks like 1080p'."
  
The resolution does indeed change, this is the whole reason for my question. I don't even use the built in settings menu to change the res, but a programm called BetterDisplay, which lets me set a specific resolution, and indeed, changing the "scaling" in settings changes the set resolution itself.

Comment: @AdamMazurkiewicz No it doesn't. The OS still uses every pixel of your 4K display, it's just the content is made a different size. Although BetterDisplay might be doing something different.

Comment: "Your display has a pixel density of 102ppi, which is very low, and so you're always going to see some lack of smoothness."
This is maybe true, but the blurriness comes from the display trying to display a signal which is not in it's native resolution

Comment: @AdamMazurkiewicz So what happens when you use the native resolution?

Comment: Well I am not going to argue with you. I know that it is changing the res, since only 4k and FullHD (due to integer scaling) settings look sharp. Any other scaling setting is blurry as display has to try and match pixels on an imperfect pixel grid.

Comment: In native resolution, the font itself is not being properly displayed due to relatively low DPI and lack of macOS proper support of it. This is absolutly not a problem on the same display on windows.